# In a simulator, outputing +/-5V peak AC through bridge rectifier then opamp buffer gives 5V DC output... software error or does this really happen?

Tags: voltage, rectifier, buffer, bridge-rectifier

In a [circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) I'm using it shows that if I run an AC voltage through a bridge rectifier and output that to a op amp buffer, the voltage at the input of the opamp (and hence the output) is the peak AC voltage I set on the source. Is this a software error or does this happen in real circuits? If so... why? If I understand correctly the AC source should always have a neutral terminal and the other terminal oscillates between +ve and -ve voltage...

Here is a permalink to the design in the circuit simulator if you want to check it out in action: it animates the voltage and current flow in real time. [Circuit Simulator Permalink](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%202.803162489452614%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20176%20112%2064%20112%200%0Aw%20176%2048%2064%2048%200%0Ad%20176%2048%20208%2080%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20176%20112%20208%2080%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20144%2080%20176%2048%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20144%2080%20176%20112%201%200.805904783%0Ag%20144%2080%20128%2080%200%0Aw%2064%2064%2064%2048%200%0Aw%2064%2096%2064%20112%200%0Av%2064%2096%2064%2064%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aa%20272%2096%20368%2096%201%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aw%20368%2096%20368%20144%200%0Aw%20368%20144%20272%20144%200%0Aw%20272%20144%20272%20112%200%0Aw%20272%2080%20208%2080%202%0Ar%20384%20224%20448%20224%200%20100%0Aw%20384%20224%20320%20224%202%0Aw%2080%20240%20128%20240%200%0Av%2080%20240%2080%20208%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20176%20240%20176%20256%200%0Aw%20176%20208%20176%20192%200%0AT%20176%20208%20128%20208%200%204%201%200.014313344849754748%20-0.0034582241175983366%200.999%0Ag%20256%20224%20240%20224%200%0Ad%20256%20224%20288%20256%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20256%20224%20288%20192%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20288%20256%20320%20224%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20288%20192%20320%20224%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20288%20192%20176%20192%200%0Aw%20288%20256%20176%20256%200%0Ag%20448%20224%20448%20256%200%0Aw%20192%20368%2080%20368%200%0Aw%20192%20304%2080%20304%200%0Ad%20192%20304%20224%20336%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20192%20368%20224%20336%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20160%20336%20192%20304%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20160%20336%20192%20368%201%200.805904783%0Aw%2080%20320%2080%20304%200%0Aw%2080%20352%2080%20368%200%0Av%2080%20352%2080%20320%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20224%20400%20224%20432%200%0As%2080%20208%20128%20208%200%200%20false%0Aw%20160%20336%20128%20336%200%0Aw%20128%20336%20128%20400%200%0Aw%20128%20400%20224%20400%200%0Ar%20288%20400%20288%20336%200%20100%0Aw%20224%20336%20240%20336%200%0Aw%20224%20400%20240%20400%200%0Aw%20240%20400%20288%20400%200%0Aw%20288%20336%20240%20336%202%0Ac%20240%20336%20240%20400%200%200.01%203.4204355899199617%0Aw%20368%2096%20400%2096%202%0Ar%20400%2096%20464%2096%200%20100%0Ag%20464%2096%20464%20144%200%0Ax%2020%20289%20297%20292%200%2015%20Bridge%20Rectifier%20with%20Smoothing%20Capacitor%0Ax%2018%20177%20316%20180%200%2015%20Bridge%20Rectifier%20with%20no%20Smoothing%20Capacitor%0Ax%2018%2030%20493%2033%200%2015%20Circuit%20in%20Question:%20how%20is%20it%20outputting%205V%20with%20no%20smoothing%20capacitor?%0Ao%2014%2064%200%20551%2010%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%2048%2064%200%20551%205%200.05%201%20-1%0Ao%201%2064%200%20551%2010%200.00009765625%202%20-1%0A)

Thank you in advance!

[image: Diagram from Circuit Simulator]

Comment: For future reference, the falstad simulator, while quite nice, is **very, VERY** idealistic and simplified. It does lots of things that are completely unrealistic for real components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it probably won't work like that if you actually give a DC path for the opamp's input. And if you don't do that [all bets are off in real life](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-937.pdf).

See [adjusted simulation with DC path](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+2.803162489452614+50+5+50%0Aw+272+272+160+272+0%0Aw+272+208+160+208+0%0Ad+272+208+304+240+1+0.805904783%0Ad+272+272+304+240+1+0.805904783%0Ad+240+240+272+208+1+0.805904783%0Ad+240+240+272+272+1+0.805904783%0Ag+240+240+224+240+0%0Aw+160+224+160+208+0%0Aw+160+256+160+272+0%0Av+160+256+160+224+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aa+368+256+464+256+1+15+-15+1000000%0Aw+464+256+464+304+0%0Aw+464+304+368+304+0%0Aw+368+304+368+272+0%0Aw+368+240+304+240+2%0Ar+480+384+544+384+0+100%0Aw+480+384+416+384+2%0Aw+176+400+224+400+0%0Av+176+400+176+368+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+272+400+272+416+0%0Aw+272+368+272+352+0%0AT+272+368+224+368+0+4+1+0.021410226183827027+-0.00013770312995161444+0.999%0Ag+352+384+336+384+0%0Ad+352+384+384+416+1+0.805904783%0Ad+352+384+384+352+1+0.805904783%0Ad+384+416+416+384+1+0.805904783%0Ad+384+352+416+384+1+0.805904783%0Aw+384+352+272+352+0%0Aw+384+416+272+416+0%0Ag+544+384+544+416+0%0Aw+288+528+176+528+0%0Aw+288+464+176+464+0%0Ad+288+464+320+496+1+0.805904783%0Ad+288+528+320+496+1+0.805904783%0Ad+256+496+288+464+1+0.805904783%0Ad+256+496+288+528+1+0.805904783%0Aw+176+480+176+464+0%0Aw+176+512+176+528+0%0Av+176+512+176+480+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+320+560+320+592+0%0As+176+368+224+368+0+0+false%0Aw+256+496+224+496+0%0Aw+224+496+224+560+0%0Aw+224+560+320+560+0%0Ar+384+560+384+496+0+100%0Aw+320+496+336+496+0%0Aw+320+560+336+560+0%0Aw+336+560+384+560+0%0Aw+384+496+336+496+2%0Ac+336+496+336+560+0+0.01+3.440525284032093%0Aw+464+256+496+256+2%0Ar+496+256+560+256+0+100%0Ag+560+256+560+304+0%0Ax+116+449+386+452+0+15+Bridge+Rectifier+with+Smoothing+Capacitor%0Ax+114+337+404+340+0+15+Bridge+Rectifier+with+no+Smoothing+Capacitor%0Ax+114+190+577+193+0+15+Circuit+in+Question:+how+is+it+outputting+5V+with+no+smoothing+capacitor?%0Ar+320+256+320+304+0+100000%0Ag+320+304+320+320+0%0Aw+320+256+304+240+0%0Ao+14+64+0+551+10+0.00009765625+0+-1%0Ao+48+64+0+551+5+0.05+1+-1%0Ao+1+64+0+551+5+0.00009765625+2+-1%0A).

[image]

Comment: Beat me too it by a few seconds. I'm guessing its a the simulation engine is struggling either with some simulated capacitance somewhere, or just being confused with ground references.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: Falstad uses simplistic omamp models. The rails of that opamp (which alas it doesn't display by default) are set to +/-15V. I think LTspice it will show the opamp saturate, with a decent opamp model.

Comment: The falstad simulator op-amps have infinite input impedance, and the diodes have no leakage. It doesn't simulate wire capacitance, but with no current flow into the wire, it just sits there at whatever voltage it was driven to until something else perturbs it.

Comment: Actually LTspice has the same behavior, with the ideal diode model (but a real opamp) in there you'll see the leakage: http://imgur.com/2Fbx4l2 And more clearly if you vary the resistor to ground: http://imgur.com/NiIrhnu But if you change the diode model to 1N4148, then you can't see that anymore: http://imgur.com/02CQ9cU

Comment: You can get the same effect by varying the diode model leakage current instead: http://imgur.com/1HPdeVW (2.52n is the default LTspice value for 1N4148).

Comment: Thanks for all your input. So in real life I would indeed still have the same bridge rectifier output as I would a normal circuit without a smoothing cap?

Comment: What you'd see in real life depends what you power the opamp from : however in the best case, yes you would see the bridge rectifier output.

Comment: @Hydrox: basically yes, unless you have some amazing diodes with nearly zero leakage. Also this circuit is pretty pointless as power rectifier, because if you already have DC to power the opamp... Also if you want to do a precision peak detector, then this isn't the way to do it, although [the way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier) also relies on the interaction of the leakage currents. See http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01353A.pdf for a better source than Wikipedia on that.